# How to wait cancellation of task after Service#cancel?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Look at this example:

```java
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    //NOTICE: This is class in **other file** (here is just for example)
    private static class MyService extends Service {
        @Override
        protected Task createTask() {
            return new Task() {
                @Override
                protected Object call() throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("Service: START");

                    while(true) {
                        System.out.println("Service: ITERATION");

                        // Thread.sleep(3000); // This raise InterruptedException after cancel, but how about such code (it won't raise exception):

                        for(long i = 0; i < 1_000_000_000; i++) {
                        }

                        if (isCancelled())
                            break;
                    }

                    System.out.println("Service: END");

                    return null;
                }
            };
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        MyService myService = new MyService();
        myService.start();

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        myService.cancel();

        System.out.println(myService.getState()); // Here is `CANCELLED` already but task isn't finished yet.

        // <--- How to wait cancellation of Task here?

        System.out.println("This command must be called after `Service: END`");

        Platform.exit();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

As you known call of `Service#cancel` doesn't wait cancellation of `Task`. So, I want to block main thread and await cancellation of `Task`. How can I do it?

P.S.

Looks like `Service` doesn't provide any callback/event handler to check real cancellation of `Task`. Is it right?

Answer (score 2):

Never block the FX Application Thread.

The `Service` class does indeed define a [`setOnCancelled(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html#setOnCancelled-javafx.event.EventHandler-) method, which you use to register a callback:

```
myService.setOnCancelled(event -> {
    System.out.println("Service was cancelled");
});
```

Note that when you cancel a `Service`, it will interrupt the thread if it is blocked. So if you don't catch the `InterruptedException` it will not exit the `call` method normally. This is why you don't see the "END" message.

Full example code:

```
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class ServiceCancellationTest extends Application {

    //NOTICE: This is class in **other file** (here is just for example)
    private static class MyService extends Service<Void> {
        @Override
        protected Task<Void> createTask() {
            return new Task<Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("Service: START");

                    while(! isCancelled()) {
                        System.out.println("Service: ITERATION");
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(3000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException interrupted) {
                            System.out.println("Task interrupted");
                        }

                        if (isCancelled())
                            break;
                    }

                    System.out.println("Service: END");

                    return null;
                }
            };
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        MyService myService = new MyService();
        myService.start();

        myService.setOnCancelled(event -> {
            System.out.println("In cancelled callback: "+myService.getState()); // Here is `CANCELLED` already but task isn't finished yet.

        });

        // You should never block the FX Application Thread. To effect a pause,
        // use a pause transition and execute the code you want in its 
        // onFinished handler:

        PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(5));
        pause.setOnFinished(event -> {
            myService.cancel();
            System.out.println("After calling cancel: "+myService.getState());
            System.out.println("This command must be called after `Service: END`");

            Platform.exit();
        });
        pause.play();


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your solution in my example. You will see that this callback is called after `cancel` but task is still not cancelled/completed. So, I want to find any appropriate solution to wait cancellation of task. P.S. I known what block of main thread is bad idea, but in my case it can be appropriate solution.

Comment: Works fine for me... I will update with complete code.

Comment: Your solution doesn't print `Service: END`. It is mean that Task isn't cancelled/completed yet but state of service is set to CANCELLED already. I think now you understand a problem.

Comment: No, because it throws an exception when you cancel, so it terminates without actually reaching the statement that prints the "END" message. See further update.

Comment: Yes, I forget about `InterruptedException` but try to replace it to loop (as in updated example). In this case I have the same problem but now without side effect with `InterruptedException` (my mistake, original code doesn't throw it).

Comment: Just check the `isCancelled` flag defined in `Task` periodically (e.g. in your loop). See updated example (again; but I can't keep changing the answer as you change the question too many times).

Answer (score 2):

By default, `Service.cancel()` interrupts the **Task**. So an `InterruptedException` must be raised and your task will be terminated (forcefully).

One thing you could do is to store the created task in a global variable in your `MyService` class and override the cancel method like this:

```
class MyService extends Service {

    private Task t;

    @Override
    public boolean cancel() {
        if (t != null) {
            return t.cancel(false);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Task createTask() {
        t = new Task() { /* ... */ };
        return t;
    }
}
```

The rest will be easy. Add a change listener to the service state property (or use `setOnCanceled()` method) and do whatever you want to do after the state change, in the callback.